Are these ads excessive?
I've noticed that ads in blender.stackexchange seem to be unusually aggressive and intrusive lately (or maybe it's always been this way and I only just now noticed).
Specifically, at this moment every question on this site seems to have three Microsoft Azure ads, all saying the same words.  Two of them are on the right side panel, which I can usually successfully ignore, but one of them is between every question title and body, which I find very intrusive and cluttery, and it interferes with my ability to read questions and navigate the site.
This seems excessive.  Is it intended behavior?   Other stackexchange sites (e.g. stackoverflow, math) don't have it.

Also of note: the way that third ad appears is particularly low-quality and jarring: the question title&body look fine at first, then the question body jumps down (FOUC) leaving an inch of blank white space between the title and body, for a couple of seconds (on my slow connection), then eventually the unwelcome ad fades in to that space.  Not a good look.

I'm not seeing those, so I can't quite comment for a fact. Even disabling my ad blocker on a private window is not showing any at the moment. It may be a regional thing, not visible everywhere in the world, or maybe SE is tight on money and is trying to increase revenue from ads. Either way there is a privilege that grants users above a certain reputation the ability to see fewer ads. It is earned at 200 rep, you seem to be on the verge of earning it. Answer just one more question and you'll be able to unlock the achievement.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos Indeed, my experience suddenly became dramatically less garbage-y the moment I crossed 200 (except in incognito mode).  Thanks for heads up on that, I don't think the connection to rep would have occurred to me otherwise, and it would have been even more mystifying and chaotic feeling.
